# error: 'else' without 'if'.. what is wrong?

Tags: java

this is my code and I still don't know what is my problem

```
if ((int) ch[j]== (int) ch2)
{ for ( k=j; k<=j ; k++){
System.out.print(ch[j]+" ");
}

else 
System.out.print("Sorry we didn't find it");
```

Comment: You miss a `}`. Now, you see the importance of indent correctly your code.

Comment: Add a "}", ending your for loop

Comment: @ZouZou I'd expand that to "importance of correctly formatting your code" which includes line breaks as well. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing closing `}` for your `if`

```
if ((int) ch[j]== (int) ch2){ 
  for ( k=j; k<=j ; k++){
       System.out.print(ch[j]+" ");
    } //for loop closing
} //here (missing for if)
else 
    System.out.print("Sorry we didn't find it");
```

Use proper indentation, that will help you finding bugs like these.

Answer (score 2):

You missed a }.

Should be

```
if ((int) ch[j]== (int) ch2)
{ for ( k=j; k<=j ; k++){
System.out.print(ch[j]+" ");
}
}
else 
System.out.print("Sorry we didn't find it");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (int) ch[j] == (int) ch2)
{ 
   for ( k=j; k<=j ; k++)
   {
      System.out.print(ch[j]+" ");
   }
**}**
else 
   System.out.print("Sorry we didn't find it");
```